# java swing combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a combo box and a string array that holds all the values of the combo box in it. I erase the items from the combo box and then want to add in the values from the string array. It doesn't seem to let me just add in a string array. And I tried to itterate through the string adding items one by one but won't let me do that (or atleast the way I wrote it, it won't work).

May seem like a stupid question but I am new to working with swing in java.

Here's the code where I want to "reload" the items from the combo box:

```
String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Name: ", "", 1);
        if(str != null){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New name added: " + str, "", 1);
              nameCreator.addName(strNames, str);
              strNames = NameLoader.getNames();
              nameList.removeAllItems();
              nameList.addItem(strNames);
        }
```

EDIT: Made small typo and didn't realize what was wrong. Working now. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Mind adding some of your code that didnt work?

Comment: What goes wrong? Does nothing happen or do you get an error? If the latter, which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you used the method `addItem(Object anObject)`?

You should iterate your array an use that method:

```
String[] data = {a;b;c;d;e}
for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++){
  comboBox.addItem(data[i]);
}
```

Luca

Comment: Oh wow sorry I made a typo when I originally tried that. But now it works. Sorry I should have looked over my code before assuming it was right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to vote and check the useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to implement your own ComboBoxModel:

```
public class YourComboBoxModel implements ComboBoxModel{

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        //return selected item Object;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
        //set selected item
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        //return the element based on the index
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        //return the size of your combo box list
    }

}
```

And build your JComboBox passing that model as parameter:

```
ComboBoxModel yourModel = new YourComboBoxModel();
JComboBox yourComboBox = new JComboBox(yourModel);
```

Using a custom ComboBoxModel is the most flexible solution. It allows you to change the datastructure holding your datas, and the way you access it, modifying only the model you implemented instead of other unrelated part of code.

Comment: Why he should extend a comboBox when it already provides all what he need? Maybe I'm wrong but I think is not necessary. Am I wrong?

Comment: @lucaghera: Of course he can. But what about if in the future the data displayed in the combo box would become more complex? Using a ComboBoxModel help to separate the model from its representation. But that's only my point of view.

Comment: In this direction, I completely agree with you! But it seems more than what he need now for starting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to work with editable models for these kinds of GUI elements it is always good to use a model. For the `JComboBox` you have an easy-to-use `DefaultComboBoxModel`.

It works easily:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"Item1","Item2","Item3"});
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
```

in this way you have the model attached to the combobox, and it will display items from the array. Whenever you need to change them just do:

```
model.removeAllElements(); // if you need to empty it
model.addElement("New Item1");
model.addElement("New Item2");
model.addElement("New Item3");
model.fireContentsChanged();
```

and you'll have new items updated inside the GUI.

A bonus note: if you need to manage custom objects instead that strings you can easily add them to the `JComboBox` (in the sameway showed before), you just need to provide a custom `public String toString()` method that will manage the string representation.

In your example I don't get why you readd all the items everytime, you could just call `addItem` with the new String without removing everything and adding them back.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to add some thing in your combo box in order that you can change it easily is to describe an array list first,if you would like to be dynamic you can user a text field then in a text field you can run an array list .

```
textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(131, 52, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
```

then you have to create an array list

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
```

then you have to equal your text field text to a string

```
String str=textfield.getText();
```

then add it to your array

```
al.add(str);
```

then add al item to your combo box.

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setBounds(112, 115, 145, 20);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);
            comboBox.addItem(al);
```